# Função no JavaScript equivalente a Frac do Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi

Preciso de uma função no JavaScript que retorna a parte fracionária de um número de ponto flutuante.

Exemplo:

```
if Frac( num1 / num2 ) > 0 then begin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procurando a documentação Delphi encontrei essa função [`System.Frac()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Frac).
Segue trecho da documentação:

> ### **`function Frac(const X: Extended): Extended;`**
>
> ## Descrição
>
> Retorna a parte fracionária de um número real.
>
> No código Delphi, a função `Frac` retorna a parte fracionária do
> argumento `X`.
>
> `X` é uma expressão de tipo real. O resultado é a parte fracionária de
> `X`;
> ou seja, `Frac(X) = X - Int (X)`.

Então três coisas devem ser observadas:

- Em *javascript* o tipo numérico [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) é que mais se aproxima do tipo Delphi  [`System.Extended`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Extended).
- A documentação da função mostra o seu funcionamento `Frac(X) = X - Int (X)`.
- A função Delphi  [`System.Int()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Int) retorna a parte inteira de um número real que é equivalente ao *javascript* [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc).

Então uma possível alternativa em emular em javascript a função `Frac(X)` do Delphi seria:

```js
//Frac(X) = X - Int (X)

const num1 = 13;
const num2 = 3;

function frac(x) {
  return x - Math.trunc(x);
}


console.log(`Resultado de frac(num1/num2): ${frac(num1/num2)}`);
```

Observação:

Não foi utilizada a função [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description) pois a
função converte seu primeiro argumento para uma string antes de retorna o inteiro.

Answer (score -3):

Pelo que entendi vc precisa de alguma coisa dessa forma:

```
var numberToFraction = function( amount ) {
    // This is a whole number and doesn't need modification.
    if ( parseFloat( amount ) === parseInt( amount ) ) {
        return amount;
    }
    var gcd = function(a, b) {
        if (b < 0.0000001) {
            return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, Math.floor(a % b));
    };
    var len = amount.toString().length - 2;
    var denominator = Math.pow(10, len);
    var numerator = amount * denominator;
    var divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    numerator /= divisor;
    denominator /= divisor;
    var base = 0;
    // In a scenario like 3/2, convert to 1 1/2
    // by pulling out the base number and reducing the numerator.
    if ( numerator > denominator ) {
        base = Math.floor( numerator / denominator );
        numerator -= base * denominator;
    }
    amount = Math.floor(numerator) + '/' + Math.floor(denominator);
    if ( base ) {
        amount = base + ' ' + amount;
    }
    return amount;
};
```

Pra testar:

```
numberToFraction(0.25);
```

retornará: `"1/4"`